# In ExtJS 4 Why column rendere is not working for Objects?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to use renderer for a column inside grid. Here is the json data

```
{
    "success": true,    
    "products": [{
        "myfield": [30, 50]
    }]
}
```

Here is the code for renderer for column

```
  {
      text: "Myfield",
      dataIndex: 'myfield',
      renderer: function (val) {
          if (typeof (val) == 'object') {
              // Here am getting for 3 times 
              console.log(val);
              return val;
          } else {
              return val;
          }
      }
  }
```

In console why its printing for 3 times?

```
 [30, 50]
 [30, 50]
 [30, 50]
```

I am trying to create span elements for each value inside the array so using renderer.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It should print 1 time not 3 times. While I am passing some values like {"myfield":"30"} its only printing 1 time.

Comment: where are you calling this function? show that code also.

Comment: Is your grid loading/rendering more than once?  Are you making multiple Store request loads?  The renderer will only fire if the data changes or if the grid re-renders.

Comment: keep console.log also in `else` statement and check once how many times it is repeating.

Comment: My Grid has a store with autoload:false. I am loading the store using afterrender listener of GRID for 1 time only.

Comment: if am setting autoLoad:true inside store file its working fine and returning for 1 time. Also printed else part and its not going to else section

Answer (score 0):

The way ExtJs interpets your json is undefined, or in other words - your josn is invalid as far as ExtJs is concerned.

```
"products": [{
    // ExtJs has no way to understand this.
    "myfield": [30, 50]
}]
```

You are using:

```
dataIndex: 'myfield'
```

which means the column displays a field in a model record. A field of a model record must be of a primitive type - it cannot be an array or an object. If you think about it - it makes no sense to have an array or an object as a field value.

You should look into associations for the data you are trying to represent.

Comment: Yes we can add object in json without specifying type in model. Here am using this format "stat3Datas":{"0":"100","1":"200","2":"300"}, and its working fine!! The issue is why its printing more than once while using autoLoad:false and for explicity store load

Answer (score -1):

```
renderer:function(value, metaData, record){
         return record.raw.myfield // here you can get array and create string for rendering
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.